# django basic pagination problem

Tags: python, django, pagination

i have a microblog app, and i'm trying to paginate the entries, to show only 10 per page, for example.
though i've followed the tutorial, my pagination doesn't seem t be working.

the listing function looks like that:

```
def listing(request):
    blog_list = Blog.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(blog_list, 10)
    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page','1'))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response('profile/publicProfile.html', {"posts": posts})
```

and in my template:

```
    <div class="pagination">
<span class="step-links">
    {% if posts.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
        Page {{ posts.number }} of {{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}.
    </span>

    {% if object.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ posts.next_page_number }}">next</a>
    {% endif %}
</span>
```

thanks!

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Do you get an error?

Comment: ... apart from the fact that you're not actually displaying the posts anywhere in the template.

Comment: nope, it was just the 'guilty part of the template', not all the template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [django-pagination](http://code.google.com/p/django-pagination/) which makes it possible to implement pagination without writing a single line of Python code, you only pass list of all objects to template (i.e. `blog_list = Blog.objects.all()` in your case), and then use three tags in you template:

```
 {% load pagination_tags %}
 {% autopaginate blog_list 10 %}
 {% paginate %}
```

Comment: well, it sounds good, and the tutorial is really nice, but where can i get the pagination middleware?
My error is:

Error importing middleware pagination.middleware: "No module named pagination.middleware"

Comment: You should add it to setting.py, MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES like this:
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware',
)
In other word it's in pagination folder, middleware.py file

Comment: yes, sorry for not being accurate enough, i used 'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware', in my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, and included paginated in my installed apps, just like in the tutorial, but i get that error:

ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware pagination.middleware: "No module named pagination.middleware"
Were am i wrong?
thanks

Comment: Did you install django-pagination?

`pip install django-pagination` should work

Comment: Or `easy_install django-pagination`

Answer (score 5):

Return the [object_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-list-detail-object-list) generic view that takes the `paginate_by` argument, rather than return the `render_to_response`